# Jmeter - Connection SSH - Convert wget and keytool

Tags: ssh, command-line, jmeter, wget, keytool

I'm trying to create a jmeter test. In this test, I have to do these steps:

1. Create a connection SSH, with username and password;
2. Run an alias in this server;
3. Change the repository (cd.., cd conf);
4. Run this command `wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=URL_Proxy URL`, and save the response of this command;
5. Run this command `keytool -list -keystore file_keystore –alias “Alias”`, and save the response of this command;

Can I have your assistence?
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is [SSH Command Sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) plugin which you can use to connect to the remote server and execute an arbitrary command. The plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/):

[image]

Once you install the plugin you will be able to use SSH Command sampler for execution of shell commands on the remote machine:

[image]

Check out [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more details

The output of the SSH Command sampler can be stored via [Save responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener.

Comment: No unless you want to perform [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: I have one question, if would i execute more line command in one SSH Command?

Comment: Either use 2 SSH Command samplers or use Bash shell capabilities like `command1 && command2 && command3`

Comment: Thank you so mutch!